# SwiftUI: dismiss sheet programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI and I'm trying to implement the auth logic for my app.

I have a LoginView with a Register Button and if I click on it I use a sheet to present the RegisterView. Once the user is registered, the LoginView (on background) goes to HomeView and RegisterView should disappear. The problem is that RegisterView is not disappearing.

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel = RegisterViewModel()
@EnvironmentObject var authenticatedUser : AuthenticatedUser
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
```

```
ButtonWithLoadStateView(title: K.REGISTER, isLoading: self.$vm.isLoading) {
    self.viewModel.isLoading = true
    self.viewModel.register() { user in
        self.authenticatedUser.setLogged(user) // without this IT WORKS!
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
   }
}
```

If I remove the authenticatedUser.setLogged row then it works but it just encapsulate the user and store a token..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided code is not testable, so just only idea - try the following

```
ButtonWithLoadStateView(title: K.REGISTER, isLoading: self.$vm.isLoading) {
    self.viewModel.isLoading = true
    self.viewModel.register() { user in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.authenticatedUser.setLogged(user)
        }
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
   }
}
```

Comment: @LalaCip, I don't see your code, but most probably on settings user your view hierarchy is rebuilt so bound connection with previous presentation mode is broken. By delayed user assignment we give a chance for presentation to dismiss and only then rebuild view hierarchy.